# regular space and its neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology

Prove if $X$ is a regular topological space, each pair of distinct points have neighbourhoods whose closures do not intersect.

A space is called regular if there exists two disjoint open neighbourhoods each containing one closed set and one point respectively in that space. But how to relate that definition to the statement of the proof regarding "closure" of the neighbourhoods of each pair of distinct points?

Comment: We need further assumptions (e.g. that $X$ is $T_1$) to make this claim true. For let $X$ be a set with multiple elements equipped with the trivial topology. Then $X$ is regular, but the only neighborhood of any point is $X$ itself, and so the conclusion doesn't hold.

Comment: You should start your definition of regular with "for every closed set and a point not in it, etc." and then state the existence of disjoint neighborhoods, not the other way around.

Comment: BTW. An equivalent def'n of regularity of $X$ is that whenever $ p\in U\subset X,\;$ with $U$ open, there exists open $V$ with $p\in V\subset \overline V\subset U.$

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment: "We need further assumptions (e.g. that $X$ is $T_1$) to make this claim true. For let $X$ be a set with multiple elements equipped with the trivial topology. Then $X$ is regular, but the only neighborhood of any point is $X$ itself, and so the conclusion doesn't hold".

So, suppose $X$ is regular and $T_0$. Then $X$ is also $T_1$. Let $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$. Since $X$ is $T_1$, the set $\{y\}$ is closed, and so since $X$ is regular, we can pick open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $\{y\}$ (i.e. $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$) such that $U\cap V = \varnothing$. It follows that $x\notin \overline V$, since $x$ is contained in an open set which does not intersect with $V$. Again, since $X$ is regular and since $\overline V$ is closed with $x\notin \overline V$, we can find open neighborhoods $U'$ of $x$ and $V'$ of $\overline V$ with $U'\cap V' = \varnothing$. It follows that $\overline{U'}\cap \overline V = \varnothing$. Since $x\in U'\subseteq \overline{U'}$ and $y\in V\subseteq \overline V$ where $U', V$ are open, we're done.

Comment: Say $X=\{a,b\}$ (with $a\not=b$) where the open sets are $\emptyset$, $\{a\}$, and $X$. Isn't this a regular $T_0$ space that is not $T_1$ (known as Sierpinski doubleton).

Comment: That space isn't regular. Choose the point $a\in X$ and the closed set $V = \{b\}\subseteq X$. The only open neighborhood of $V$ is $X$, which contains $a$. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space#Relationships_to_other_separation_axioms), every regular $T_0$ space is actually Hausdorff.

Comment: You are right, but let me include a proof, since I don't just want to trust Wikipedia about that. Claim: Every regular $T_0$ space is Hausdorff (and therefore also $T_1$). Suppose $x,y$ are two different points. Since $X$ is $T_0$ there is an open $U$ that contains one of the points but not the other. Consider the case $x\in U$ (the other case being similar). The set $F=X\setminus U$ is closed. Hence there are disjoint open $V,W$ with $x\in V$, $F\subseteq W$. Since $y\not\in U$, $y\in F\subseteq W$ we are done. Thank you for the lesson (I learned something that I was supposed to know).

Comment: but there are things to fix in your answer, I believe. You say "since $X$ is $T_0$, the set $\{y\}$ is closed", don't you need to use $T_1$ here, not just $T_0$?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is regular and $T_0$ then, single points sets are closed, hence we can separate two points by disjoint open sets, now use the fact that given a point $x$ and an open set $U$ containing it we can find another open set $U_1$ containing $x$, such that it's closure is contained in $U$.

See the link for help

[Proof concerning regular space: there exist a closed set contained in any open set containing $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822520/proof-concerning-regular-space-there-exist-a-closed-set-contained-in-any-open-s)

Comment: As lots of spaces do not have intervals, that proof is inadequate.